# Menu Bar to change content in only one div

Tags: javascript, html

I have a basic webpage. At the top, there is a menu bar with 3 links. I want to change the content in only one div, depending on what link is selected. All i know is html and php. How do i link the links to change only the content div?

Comment: can you provide any code? there are many possibilities: css, javascript and php.

Answer (score 1):

This is not perfect but it changes a 'div' or in this case a 'tr'

```
<SCRIPT type="text/javascript"> 
function showoptions()
{   
    if (something == "show") 
    {
        // Show
        document.getElementById("show").style.display = '';
    }

    else
    {
        // Hide
        document.getElementById("show").style.display = 'none';
    }
}
```

```
 <table border="0" width="100%" id="table1">
    <tr>
        <td width="144">Show/hide</td>
        <td><select name="something" id="tools" onChange="showoptions()">
        <option value="show">show</option>
        <option value="hide">Hide</option>
        </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="show" style="display:none;">
        <td><input type="text" name="amount" size="5"></td>
    </tr>
<table>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you know HTML and PHP, then jumping into and using Javascript and the wonderful wrapper [jQuery](http://jquery.com) won't pose a huge learning curve.

Here's the example code to get you started based on what information you've provided:

```
<!-- include jquery reference in your head -->
<head>
    ...
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    ...

</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
   function changeDiv(link)
   {
      var contentDiv = $('#content');
      if (link == '1')
         contentDiv.html('<span style="color:red;">Link 1</span>');
      if (link == '2')
         contentDiv.html('<span style="color:red;">Link 2</span>');

   }
</script>
<div id="menu">
    <ul class="menu-item"><a id="link1" onclick="changeDiv('1')">home</a></ul>
    <ul class="menu-item"><a id="link2" onclick="changeDiv('2')">home</a></ul>
    <ul class="menu-item"><a id="link3" onclick="changeDiv('3')">home</a></ul>
</div>
<div id="content">

</div>
```

Comment: I want to pull the content from 3 different files. how will i do the links for those pages. for instance, i have a form.html file that i want to show when you click on one of the links.

Comment: If you have existing files that you want to display without leaving the current page, you can use an iframe to pull in the data from existing files.

The code would only change slightly

    
    <iframe id="frame" src="form.html" width="100%" height="300">
      <p>Your browser does not support iframes.</p>
    </iframe>